# How to conditionally apply style color to an active tab

Tags: react-hooks

I have a tab that show contents base on the tab clicked, How do I conditionally add a background color to the active tab, here is my code

```
const [active, setActive] = useState(0);
    const handleClick = e => {
      const index = parseInt(e.target.id, 0);
      if (index !== active) {
        setActive(index);
        console.log(index)
      }
    };



<ul>
    <li>
      <a onClick={handleClick} active={active ? 0 : 0}  id={0}>Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a onClick={handleClick} active={active ? 1 : 0}  id={1}>Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a onClick={handleClick} active={active ? 2 : 0}  id={2}>Tab 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>


      <Content active={active ===0}>
       <h1> Content1</h1>
     </Content>
      <Content active={active ===1}>
       <h1> Content2</h1>
     </Content>
      <Content active={active ===2}>
       <h1> Content2</h1>
     </Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1: Using class name**

add a className to the active tab based on the `active` state. And then style that active tab from CSS.

```
    <div>
      <ul className={"tabsContainer"}>
        <li>
          <a
            onClick={handleClick}
            className={active === 0 ? "active" : "inactive"}
            id={0}
          >
            Tab 1
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a
            onClick={handleClick}
            className={active === 1 ? "active" : "inactive"}
            id={1}
          >
            Tab 2
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a
            onClick={handleClick}
            className={active === 2 ? "active" : "inactive"}
            id={2}
          >
            Tab 3
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tabsContainer > li > a{
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer

}
.tabsContainer > li > a.active{
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff
}
```

Here is the working sandbox example:- https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-turing-fx754

**Method 2: Using inline style**

Other method is to add the inline style conditionally.

```
    <div>
      <ul className={"tabsContainer"}>
        <li>
          <a
            onClick={handleClick}
            id={0}
            style={active === 0 ? {background:'green'} : {background:'#fff'}}
          >
            Tab 1
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a
            onClick={handleClick}
            id={1}
            style={active === 1 ? {background:'green'} : {background:'#fff'}}
          >
            Tab 2
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a
            onClick={handleClick}
            id={2}
            style={active === 2 ? {background:'green'} : {background:'#fff'}}
          >
            Tab 3
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Using class names is a better and efficient option as it gives more control for using pseudo selectors of CSS and also code repetition remains less.